# Introduction to Linear Algebra 4th Edition by Gilbert Strang fully written solutions / or another book with fully written solutions!

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I have gotten my hands on the following book Introduction to Linear Algebra 4th Edition by Gilbert Strang and it's not sufficient for my learning needs, at least not on it's own.

I have access to the solutions of the problems located at [this](http://www.scribd.com/doc/86849289/Introduction-to-Linear-Algebra-4th-Edition-by-Gilbert-Strang-Solutions) website.

The solutions stated *do not help me learn* linear algebra. Why? I require a *fully* written out solution explaining every step instead of a compact summary. Does anyone know where I can acquire these type of solutions for this book?

*Alternatively* tell me *which* linear algebra book has fully written out solutions. I need to see the process in full detail, reading abstract sentences just does not do it for me.

Comment: But the link you have posted provides fully written solutions. It is an instructor solution manual. I dont think you will be able to find something more detailed than what you have found.

Comment: It is, imo, extremely inlikely there are *fully* developed solutiong of **any** book, as such a book would probably be 3-4 times as fat as the original one, or more....and who has the time to do such a thing and for free? Anyway, the McGraw Hill Schaum series has lots of books on mathematics subjects with complete solutions to hundreds of exercises (though I'm not sure whether they are fully written).

Comment: @PedroArbizu The link does *not* display fully written solutions, it displays abstract, compact solutions. A fully written solution would involve for example gaussian row reduction calculations.

Comment: @Timbuc This is what I'm afraid of! I need to see detail before I can see abstract. I'll look at the book you mentioned!

Comment: you have to do some work then. Life is tough. There is not fully written solution manual in life.

Comment: @PedroArbizu This hopefully will change when the mathematicians writing these books realize that one of the main reasons the majority of people find math hard, is *because* the current books are so abstract.

Comment: @KarlMorrison Mathematicians who know enough to write such a book are too busy doing something else. See if [this](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/) book pleases you. If you're studying at a university, you might try to contact the students in the math department, with any luck you'll find someone like me who solves every problem from (almost) every course.

Comment: @GitGud I presume and I hope that they are doing greater deeds with their knowledge. However that does not discourage them from getting someone else to write the solutions fully out. Do they not want to share what they think is the world to them with the world? It currently resembles a *club* to be able to understand math properly and enjoy it. Thank you for the link, all help is appreciated fully!

Comment: @KarlMorrison Textbooks are generally meant to *accompany* a course in the subject -- not completely supplant it.  As such, you'll just need to work harder to make sure everything MAKES SENSE TO YOU.  If you're not sure and have questions, that's what this site is for.  Also, if you're not going to be learning in a traditional classroom environment, you might look into the growing open source learning movement.  For instance, Dr. Strang himself has a set of lecture videos available for free on [ocw.mit.edu](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm).

Comment: @KarlMorrison This is just my opinion, so take it for what it's worth. I think the main reasons why such books aren't written are that some teachers are of the opinion that a student must struggle to be able to understand, so forget about these writing full solutions. Others don't write these books because there's life: jobs, lessons to prepare, notes for the lessons which are often turned into books (but this is more on the theoretical part) and research. My point being that even when it comes to sharing the knowledge, there are priorities over full solutions (at least for these people).

Comment: @Bye_World My classroom isn't sufficient enough for me to learn this subject as there are no examples being shown and the only reference we receive is "read the book" which is far to abstract for me (at this time). Work harder? I work my ass off just so you know and it's getting me *nowhere*, hence my question here. As for asking questions, I would be asking questions for nearly every question in my book which would lead to this community crucifying me. Thank you for the open source alternative I will surly look into it!

Comment: @KarlMorrison I sympathize. I am of the opinion that lectures and books in general are too tough. I had to tough it out. I hope you find the solution that fits you best.

Comment: @KarlMorrison I didn't mean to imply that you weren't working hard, and I just assumed by the phrasing of your question that you were trying to study this on your own.  My advice, then, in addition to checking out online video lectures, is to talk to your professor and tell him/her your concerns.  Often professors are more than willing to add more examples, etc, into their lectures if they think students are struggling.  Also, if you have a TA for your class, go talk to him/her during his/her office hours.  Working out problems with someone looking over your shoulder can be very helpful.

Comment: @GitGud Finally a reasonable motive as to why this happens. Of all the subjects I have read math is by far the one I am struggling with most. As a programmer I like logic, I'd like to think mathematicians and programmers have logic in common. I find it however not logical for these books to be so abstract especially for beginners of a completely new subject within mathematics. As for my opinion it's a major pity that these books are stuck it what seems to me as the 19th century. Math needs to be opened up to the world.

Comment: @KarlMorrison To be perfectly honest I think most authors (and lecturers) have been at such a high intellectual level for so long that they don't realize how big the gaps in their texts are when read by a less capable person. Also most people who end up writing books were already the best students in their time, so the distance gap to the regular reader becomes even larger.

Comment: @GitGud Another good point there, would explain certainly a lot!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative book that you can try is: [Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon](http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/). The book is completely open source and it has a variety of exercises for you try with *full solutions*.

Highlights from the website:

> - The coverage is standard: linear systems and Gauss's method, vector    spaces, linear maps and matrices, determinants, and eigenvectors eigenvalues.
> - It is Free. The book is Freely available, including its source.
> - The approach is developmental. Although it covers the requisite    material by proving things, it does not assume that students already able at abstract work. Instead, it proceeds with a great of motivation, many computational examples, and exercises that from routine verifications to a few challenges. The goal is, in context of developing the material of an undergraduate linear course, to help raise each student's level of mathematical maturity.
> - Extensive exercise sets, with worked answers to all exercises.    Sometimes material described on the web as a book is really someone's lecture notes. That's fine but from notes to a book is a long way. That includes things like figures and an index, but most importantly means exercises. Each subsection here has many, spanning a range difficulty, each with a worked answer, including proofs.
> - Popular. This book has been downloadable since 1996 and has been used    in hundreds of classes at many schools, as well as by individuals for independent study. Applications. Each finishes with four or five short supplemental topics. These are for reading or projects, or for small group work.
> - Extras. You can get beamer slides to use in class, and a lab manual    using Sage. Prerequisite: typically one semester of calculus (some examples use the derivative operation).
> - Reviews. Here are some: [the Mathematical Association of America review](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/19/?pa=reviews&sa=viewBook&bookId=72055), [the American Institute of Mathematics](http://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/hefferon/), one from a [longstanding site for free texts](http://www.theassayer.org/cgi-bin/asbook.cgi?book=29).